# Flatten Map<String,Set<String>> to List<String> (CSV conversion) with streams

Tags: java, java-stream

Given input (Map key:value)

```
"a":["e","c","d"]
"b":["c"]
```

Desired sorted output:

```
"a,c"
"a,d"
"a,e"
"b,c"
```

Comment: Google "how to use flatMap with java stream"

Comment: It could really be as simple as : `map.forEach((k,v) -> v.forEach( val -> list.add(k + "," +val)))` . Give it a try once!

Comment: @Naman that's a bad solution, it's not very functional

Comment: @hey_you alright, what is not functional in it? could you elaborate *bad* here in terms of what?

Comment: @Naman the fact that you're using foreach everywhere, might as well write a normal for instead.

Comment: @hey_you Just using them everywhere doesn't make them bad I would say. Anyway, I am neither mutating any object iterated on nor producing any other side effects. So I really hope the for loop can be represented as the `forEach` safely in this case.

Comment: @hey_you simple flatMap is probably not enough, i don't want to just flatten to all values, but as described above.

Comment: The edit makes the question worse. Why would you want to represent numbers as strings and then need them to be sorted by numeric values?

Comment: @Naman you have a point, I edit once more to avoid confusion on sorting rules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could possibly be looking for is using flatMap with a sort of values tweaked to compare converted integer values as :

```
return map.entrySet().stream()
        .flatMap(e -> e.getValue().stream()
                .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(Integer::parseInt)) // or just .sorted()
                .map(v -> e.getKey() + "," + v))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

To keep this readable, it's best to split the code in two methods, just so you don't inline the `flatMap` logic:

```
public List<String> toPairs(Map<String, Set<String> map) {
    return map.entrySet().stream()
        .flatMap(this::entryPairs)
        .sorted() // if you want the whole output to be sorted
        .collect(Collectors.toList())
}

private Stream<String> entryPairs(Map.Entry<String, Set<String>> entry) {
    return entry.getValue().stream()
        // .sorted() // you can sort the values for each key here, but this is useless if you're sorting above
        .map(v -> entry.getKey() + ',' + v)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is a perfect solution but it is working.

```
map.entrySet().stream()
  .map(entry.getValue().stream()
     .sorted()
     .map(value->entry.getKey()+","+value)
     .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"))
  )
  .sorted()
  .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
```